# Angular error: Cannot read property 'MissingTranslationStrategy' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular

I have next error using *ng serve*:

**error in Cannot read property 'MissingTranslationStrategy' of undefined.**

I was reading in google and not much information for it.

I don't know what you need the over you ask me I will show, certenly I think is nothing about project information (not sure). I installed a config.ts like this link: [click me](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler/src/config.ts) or [angular information](https://angular.io/api/core/MissingTranslationStrategy)

I tested using ng serve.

My versions are:

```
node: v10.13.0
npm:  v6.4.1
Angular CLI: 7.0.6
OS: win32 x64   

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.6
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.6
@schematics/angular          7.0.6
@schematics/update           0.10.6
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this error shows up when you don't initialize the property.
In this case, "MissingTranslationStrategy" property is not initialized in your `.ts` file. So, when you try to run your project using `ng serve`, it fails (Assuming you had done all your configurations properly).

(For more details, you can refer to this link: [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/i18n))

Comment: what I did to solve it is to create a new project and copy there my src .

Comment: @David, That means your "node_modules" and/or "package-lock.json" was not correct. So, when you created a new project and tried running your source code there, it was successful.